# Get all combinations of two from a column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with names of competitors on Column A.
I need to create a list of all possible combinations of 2 competitors.

In the example I have put 5 people. In the list all competitors compete once against eachother.

```
John
Melinda
David
Samantha
Eddy
```

```
John-Melinda
Melinda-David
David-Samantha
Samantha-Eddy
John-David
Melinda-Samantha
David-Eddy
etc....
```

I can only get all combinations (so also 3 compeating, 4 competing etc). Like this.

```
Eddy
Samantha
Samantha + Eddy
David
David + Eddy
David + Samantha
David + Samantha + Eddy
Melinda
Melinda + Eddy
Me<br>inda + Samantha
Melinda + Samantha + Eddy
Melinda + David
Melinda + David + Eddy
Melinda + David + Samantha
Melinda + David + Samantha + Eddy
John
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You did not tag it with what you want to use: excel-formula or vba.  Also you need to show what you have tried.  What got you the results you are showing that are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your competitors are listed in a **Table** which you have named `Names`,

[image]

and no restrictions as to Excel version since you have listed none, here is a formula that will return all the combinations of your list of names:

```
=BYROW(
    LET(
        y, ROWS(Names),
        x, MOD(
            INT((SEQUENCE(2 ^ y) - 1) / 2 ^ SEQUENCE(, y, 0)),
            2
        ),
        IF(
            FILTER(x, MMULT(x, SEQUENCE(y) ^ 0) = 2),
            TRANSPOSE(Names),
            ""
        )
    ),
    LAMBDA(arr, TEXTJOIN("-", TRUE, arr))
)
```

[image]

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- After you have pasted the code below, you must also add the custom function

  - Right click in the Queries window (on the left) and select to create a new query from `Other Sources => Blank'
  - Paste the custom function code into the window that opens
  - Rename the custom function (`Query Settings => Properties => Name`): `fnCombo`
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Main Query***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Names"]}[Content],
    #"Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Names", type text}}),

//generate a list of 2 digit combos corresponding to 
//  position in list of names   
    comboList = fnCombo(0,Table.RowCount(#"Type")-1),

//extract names corresponding to positions in combolist
//   and combine the names for the matches
    matches =
        List.Transform(comboList, each Text.Combine(
           {#"Type"{_{0}}[Names], #"Type"{_{1}}[Names]}, "-")),

//convert to table so will have desired column header
    result = Table.FromColumns({matches}, type table[Matches=text])
in
    result
```

***Custom Function***
*rename: fnCombo*

```
// fnCombo
//generate all possible combinations of numbers from min to max

(min as number, max as number)=>
let 
    nums = {min..max},
    x = List.Generate(
        ()=>[a={nums{0},nums{1}}, idx=0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(nums)-1,
        each [a={nums{0}, nums{[idx]+2}}, idx=[idx]+1],
        each [a]
    ),
    result = if (min+1)=max then x else List.Combine({x,fnCombo(min+1,max)})
 in 
    result
```

***Power Query Output***
*Note that the order is different from the formula output above*
[image]